# Error when downloading dependencies for org.apache.hive.hive-exec version 1.2.1

Tags: scala, hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

I am trying to download the Hive jar in sbt and I am getting the following error. Have anyone encountered this? please let me know what is the correct hive version I need to download in order to create a create a class extending the GenericUDF class

This is my SBT file

```
name := "Test"  version := "0.1"  scalaVersion := "2.11.8"   libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-exec" % "1.2.1"
```

The below is the error message I am getting

```
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (*:update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.pentaho#pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm;5.1.5-jhyde: not found
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.pentaho#pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm;5.1.5-jhyde: not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add conjars repo. It will download required library. add the below lines into your build.sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-exec" % "1.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.pentaho" % "pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm" % "5.1.5-jhyde" % Test

resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
resolvers += "Cascading repo" at "http://conjars.org/repo"
```

Comment: conjar only hosts 5.1.4, hive-exec 2.x requires 5.1.5. public pentaho repo url from @Mahmoud-yusuf works !

Answer (score 2):

In case the same error happens while using gradle, adding this to the `repositories` section at `build.gradle` file solved it for me:

```
maven { url "https://public.nexus.pentaho.org/repository/proxy-public-3rd-party-release" }
```